# Insert count number of elements in columns into table in R

Tags: r

I'm working in R and I've got a matrix with `A`, `B` and `NA` values, and I would like to count the number of `A` or `B` or `NA` values in every column and insert the results into the table. I used the code below to account the `A`, `B` and `NA`.

```
mydata <- matrix(c(rep("A", 8), rep("B", 2), rep(NA, 2), rep("A", 4),
rep(c("B", "A", "A", "A"), 2), rep("A", 4)), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

myFun <- function(x) {
data.frame(n.A = sum(x == "A", na.rm = TRUE), n.B = sum(x == "B",
na.rm = TRUE), n.NA = sum(is.na(x)))
}

count <- apply(mydata, 2, myFun)
```

Now, I need to insert the results from count `(count <- apply(mydata, 2, myFun))` into the a dataframe as a table with only a header.

Comment: Can you post an example of the expected output? Do you just mean `> do.call(rbind, count)`?

Answer (score 2):

Almost identical in concept to mnel's answer, you can also try the following in base R:

```
sapply(as.data.frame(mydata), 
       function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique(as.vector(mydata))), 
                         useNA = "always"))
#      V1 V2 V3 V4
# A     4  6  6  6
# B     3  1  0  0
# <NA>  0  0  1  1
```

Here, rather than manually specifying the factor levels, I've made use of the data in `mydata`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest with using `plyr` and `adply` or `ldply`

You  can replace `myfun` with a call to table.

```
library(plyr)
adply(mydata,2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = c('A','B')), useNA = 'always'))
#   X1 A B NA
# 1  1 4 3  0
# 2  2 6 1  0
# 3  3 6 0  1
# 4  4 6 0  1
```

If you have large data, then `plyr` isn't the way go. `apply` will work nicely

```
apply(mydata, 2, function(x) {
          xx <- table(factor(x, levels = c('A','B')), useNA = 'always')
          names(xx) <- c('nA','nB', 'nNA')
          xx}) 


   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
nA     4    6    6    6
nB     3    1    0    0
nNA    0    0    1    1
```

Comment: So, in this approach not working because my data set is very large as 600 x 600,000 dimension. So give the message Error in splitter_a(.data, .margins, .expand) : Invalid margin

Comment: The output file is similar given above, but is not working with my data. I would like the total number by column.

Comment: Isn't the total number always the same?